# Find minmax of custom data type using algorithm header

Tags: c++, qt, stdvector, stl-algorithm

I have a vector of `QPointF` and I need to find the minimum and maximum `y` values because I need to know what is the amplitude of the data in the vector.

I use QPointF but for adding each new element I sum up the `x` value of other elements in the vector:

```
std::vector<QPointF> points;

int getTotalTime() {
    int time = 0;
    for(QPointF& p : points) {
        time += p.x();
    }

    return time;
}

void addPointToGraph(const QPointF& p) {
    if(points.size() == 0) {
        points.push_back(p);
        return;
    }

    points.push_back(QPointF(getTotalTime() + p.x(), p.y()));
}
```

So therefore I will have a continues waveform...this works fine! But now I need to find the amplitude of the waveform so I need to find minimum and maximum `y` values of the `points` vector.

E.g. I need a function to return min `y` and max `y` like a `std::pair<float,float>` I have seen in the algorithm header we have something like:

```
  std::array<int,7> foo {3,7,2,9,5,8,6};

  auto result = std::minmax_element (foo.begin(),foo.end());

  // print result:
  std::cout << "min is " << *result.first;
  std::cout << ", at position " << (result.first-foo.begin()) << '\n';
  std::cout << "max is " << *result.second;
  std::cout << ", at position " << (result.second-foo.begin()) << '\n';
```

The question is how can I use the same idea and go over my own vector and only check for `y` of the points?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`std::minmax_elements`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/minmax_element), like many other algorithms, provides an overload that accepts a custom predicate:

> ```
> template< class ForwardIt, class Compare >
> std::pair<ForwardIt,ForwardIt> 
>     minmax_element( ForwardIt first, ForwardIt last, Compare comp );
> ```

You can use that with a *lambda expression* to achieve what you want:

```
const auto result = std::minmax_element(foo.begin(), foo.end(), 
    [](const QPointF& a, const QPointF& b){ return a.y() < b.y(); });
```

Answer (score 3):

There is an overload which takes comparison predicate that you might use:

```
std::vector<QPointF> points /* = .. */;

std::minmax_element (points.begin(), points.end(),
                     [](const QPointF& lhs, const QPointF& rhs){
                         return lhs.y() < rhs.y();
                     });
```